# How to change my website's appearance in a Facebook wall post?

Tags: html, facebook

When posting a website link in a Facebook wall post, Facebook fetches some content (title, text and image) from the website to show it to readers. Is there a way I can adjust / propose which content is used / preferred by Facebook?

[image]

I found someone saying to use `<meta property="og:image" content="image.jpg">`, but this doesn't seem to have any effect. But maybe Facebook caches these results for a while?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Indeed. You should have in the page the **html code** that tells Facebook what to display.

Check the **documentation** on the Open Graph Protocol for more information:

http://developers.facebook.com/docs/opengraph/

And you should clean Facebook's **cache** while testing, to avoid inconsistencies between what is on the page and what is shown in Facebook. You can use this tool:

http://developers.facebook.com/tools/debug

Comment: Thanks a lot for the place to look at! It is hard to find this if you don't know how it is called.